# python ctypes does not show console

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ctypes

I want to hide the console and show. But after I hid it does not show

```
ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW(None, "L"), 1 if click_thread.hide_status else 0 )
```

Comment: What's *"L"*? Make sure to check the return values for functions. And most important read first: [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011).

Comment: "L" is name of window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to fully define the `.argtypes` and `.restype` of each function you use.  `ctypes` defaults aren't always best.  Below works:

```py
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

SW_HIDE = 0
SW_SHOW = 5

dll = ct.WinDLL('user32')
# BOOL ShowWindow(HWND hWnd, int nCmdShow);
dll.ShowWindow.argtypes = w.HWND, ct.c_int
dll.ShowWindow.restype = w.BOOL
# HWND FindWindowW(LPCWSTR lpClassName, LPCWSTR lpWindowName);
dll.FindWindowW.argtypes = w.LPCWSTR, w.LPCWSTR
dll.FindWindowW.restype = w.HWND

h = dll.FindWindowW(None, 'Console')
dll.ShowWindow(h, SW_HIDE)
input(': ')
dll.ShowWindow(h, SW_SHOW)
```